# problema al crear una table en mysql

Tags: mysql

Quiero crear una tabla en MySQL para hacerla funcionar como la validación de postfix:

```
create table virtual ( 
    address varchar(255) not null primary key unique, 
    goto varchar(255) not null 
);
```

quiero hacer esta simple tabla pero me salta el siguiente error. Sé que es gramática pero no entiendo nada de MySQL:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'virtual (
>   address varchar(255) not null primary key unique,
>   goto varchar(255) no' at line 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buenas a tu consulta le falta indicar el nombre de la tabla, ya que la palabra VIRTUAL es una palabra reservada, prueba con lo siguiente :

```
create table nombre_de_tu_tabla
( 
    address varchar(255) not null primary key unique, 
    goto varchar(255) not null
);
```

Comment: desde ya muchas gracias muy amable ..

Comment: de nada, recuerda votar positivo y/o marcar la respuesta como correcta para ayudar a la comunidad, Saludos.

Comment: ahora lo hago perdón muchas gracias como se vota positivo ?

Comment: debes hacer click en la flecha que indica hacia arriba en mi respuesta, tambien si es la respuesta correcta debes marcar como respuesta correcta y aparecera un ticket verde

Saludos